# What is the purpose of the printf() function in PHP?

Tags: php, printf

This may seem like a really daft question, but what is the reason for the existence of the `printf()` function in PHP?

It seems to me that that using `echo` will achieve the exact same results, with the added bonus that you don't get confused if you have several variables being output on one line (true, you can use `%1$s` as opposed to just `%s`, but it can still get messey with a few variables all being declared).

I know you can also define the type of the variable, without the need to amend it before outputting the string, but to me that doesn't seem like enough to warrent creating a function.

Maybe I'm wrong, maybe I'm missing something obvious, but if someone can help me to understand why it exists (so that I know whether or not I should really be using it!) I'd appriciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Because `echo 'Hello '.$name.'.';` and `printf('Hello %s.', $name);` produce exactly the same results. That was the basis of my question, to find and understand the differences between them to ensure that I am coding efficiently and using the resources that PHP provides to the best of my ability.

Comment: Well, yes, but there is 14 additional formatting options listed that won't produce the same output, right?

Comment: I understand that `printf()` offers the ability the produce output with formatting all in one go, but what the manual didn't explain was whether or not there were any advatages to using it over `echo` if you are outputting a string that contains, say two variables, that are already formatted as you wish. So it was about making sure that I was uing `printf()`, and `echo`, for the right things, and not missing out on important performance gains that may have existed.

Comment: fair enough, though questioning the entire existence of `printf` then is somewhat odd (to me). Also performance-wise you are in the realm of micro-optimizations here.

Comment: Maybe the question was a little to hash on the function, but that wasn't the intention.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

printf() is a port of C's printf() function, so people who got a background writing C code are more familiar with the syntax and will prefer it.
However, most people who start with PHP find it rather confusing.

For comparison:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
        mysql_real_escape_string($user),
        mysql_real_escape_string($password));
```

(I used sprintf(), which is the same as printf but it won't actually print the string, it just returns it)

---

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='" . mysql_real_escape_string($user) . "' AND password='" . mysql_real_escape_string($password) . "'";
```

It's just a matter of preference!

Comment: It certainly was confusing when I first saw it! So there are no specific performance advantages from using it then?

Comment: Not really, looking at these benchmarks: http://www.nutt.net/2004/12/09/php-benchmarking-echo-vs-print-vs-printf/

Comment: Great stuff, just making sure it didn't have a fairly essential purpose that I didn't really understand! Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not personal taste, they're quite different functions with different purposes.

Comment: @Jeroen quoting a 2004 microoptimization benchmark in 2012 is *not* helpful.

Answer (score 11):

`echo` is language construct, `printf` is a function. It means that so you won't be able to use `echo` in the same way as `printf`.

**IT'S NOT JUST PERSONAL TASTE**

Take a look to the manual pages for both functions:

- echo: http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php
- printf: http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php

This topic is discussed there, for example, you cannot call `echo` with variable functions. Moreover the way they get and manage the input is different. If you do not need the parameters **FORMATTING** provided by `printf` you should use `echo` (it's slightly faster).

### Examples

I insist again on some keywords: **formatting** and **function**.
The use of `printf` isn't to concatenate strings or to build a string from placeholders but to do it with custom formatting (possibly from configuration, user inputs or whatever else).

I write some code to explain what I mean (original source in the links I posted).

This code is not valid, `echo` is not a function so it won't return the printed value (you may use `print` or `sprintf` for this but `print` does not provide string concatenation).

```
($some_var) ? echo 'true' : echo 'false';
```

Following code prints a formatted string, in this case the format comes from a literal variable but it may comes from (for example) a GET request or whatever else. Can you rewrite it with `echo` and the formatting string taken from the configuration?

```
%format = "%'.-15.15s%'.6.6s\n";
printf($format, $heading1, $value1);
```

Answer (score 4):

**This is about separating static string and formatting, and data.**

This separation is encouraged in every programming language that I know of because:

- **intent of programmer is clearer and enforced**

  *intent is clear*: When you read this you know what type is awaited for each field:

  ```
     printf("a: %.2f, b: %s, c: %d", $a, $b, $c)
  ```

  *intent is enforced*: silly type errors are limited (as for the security concerns).
- **it's more secure**

  Because it limits silly injection of unexpected meta-strings:

  ```
     $avg = 3.1415;
     // $avg = '3</td><a href="http://www.badsite.com">pawned!</a>';
     printf("average: %.2f", $avg);
  ```

  It's much worse in SQL...
- **usually much easier to read**

  Appart than you have more clues to the intent of the writer, the string 
     is clearly in one unique clear block. Data are cleanly listed one by one
     after. You don't overuse things like `"`, `.` all over the place.
- **it's very powerfull**

  I'm curious to see how you would do the following without `printf`:

  ```
     printf("%.2f %5d", $v1, $v2);
  ```
- **it's some sort of standard of programming**

  A lot of other programming languages (C, C++, Java, Python, Bash...) will have
     similar `printf` format and way to treat strings.
     So its good for you to know it, and for those who already know, it's easier.
     And as a consequence there are plenty of docs and tutorials everywhere on the
     subject, and a wikipedia page for it: [print format string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string)
- **The strings can be separated from your data automatically**

  And this means it's available for translation or syntax correction.

**You'll find similar concerns with:**

- prepared statements in mysql that are now enforced with `mysql_query` being 
  deprecated in php 5.5 in favor for prepared statements.
- All templating language: where you have the template usually in a different langage, 
  and the data the other side to render the template.
- The more general topic is covered on wikipedia: [string interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation)

**A last precision:**

`echo` does nothing more than outputing a string. And `printf` does string interpolation, and outputs a string.

So to be fair, we are here comparing building string via *string concatenation* vs *string interpolation*. As there's nothing wrong to output a string with `echo`. So this is not about `echo` but how you make your string. You are doing *string interpolation* even when using `echo` like this:

```
echo sprintf("avg: %.3f", $avg);
```

But then, well there are no more difference between this last form and:

```
printf("avg: %.3f", $avg);
```

Answer (score 2):

`printf` probably exists because PHP was created in C, and `printf` is traditionally used to output formatted strings in C.  `printf` can actually do a lot more than `echo` because it can output variables in a variety of formats including decimals to certain places and probably a lot more.

That being said, you can do anything that `printf` can do with some combination of PHP functions, and it may make more sense depending upon your background.

Comment: So it's kind of a 'catch-all' function for outputting text, one that can reduce the amount of coding for those that learn to use it, but doesn't offer any specific performance advantage?

Comment: @DavidGard it probably does offer an advantage (i.e. it may be faster to use `printf("%f02", $some_float)` over `echo number_format($some_float, 2)`, but probably not by very much.  It's not really a catch-all, it's mostly just a hold-over from C.  You can do quite a bit with it, though.  See the format section of http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: Thaks for your time, will have a read, but as long as I'm not missing a really important reason for using this then I'm happy!

Answer (score 1):

I'll just explain what I did so you get a clear difference, I'm not a PHP Pro, so maybe I'm wrong and there is a better or easier approach, and also my example may be not so useful to you as well.

I pass each string I want to translate to a function, and it returns the translated string, based on source string and current language, this way it would translate:

> "The cat has %d kittens." (english) <=> "Katua %d kume ditu." (euskera)

The fact is that the splitted string for the echo couldn't be translated, as the part previous to the number is not the same for every language, so it must be translated as a "single entity".

Answer (score 0):

It's legacy from C inherited by the PHP language

function http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/

Answer (score 0):

printf takes input differently: you can provide a format string and then list all the required input (just like in C/C++).

'echo' and 'print' only take strings and are easier to use.

Your wish, Your style :)

**NOT THAT:**

as Others have said echo is a language construct and printf is a real function,
You can do lot with printf.

People coming from C/C++ background know a lot of format strings like %f, %d, %.2f and what not !!!!!
They would prefer printf to echo for this scenario as these floating point precison format and others will be at their finger-tips.
They wd prefer these over PHP's inbuilt format functions.